# Why I can't predict my Keras model with 128 batch size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

First one sorry for my bad English. I am creating a Keras LSTM model for predicting stock prices. Thats my code:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.layers.core import Dense,Activation,Dropout,Flatten,Reshape
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import keras as kr
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras import optimizers
veri =pd.read_csv("eurusd.csv")
veri['trh'] = pd.to_datetime(veri.trh, format='%d.%m.%Y')
########################
del veri['puan']
del veri['yuzde']
del veri['sira']
del veri['trh']
df_train, df_test = train_test_split(veri, train_size=0.8, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)
print("Train and Test size", len(df_train), len(df_test))
x = df_train.loc[:,:].values
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x)
x_test = scaler.transform(df_test.loc[:,:])
TIME_STEPS=7
BATCH_SIZE=128
def build_timeseries(mat, y_col_index):

    # y_col_index tahmin etmek istediğimiz değerin sütun numarası
    # total number of time-series samples would be len(mat) - TIME_STEPS
    dim_0 = mat.shape[0] - TIME_STEPS #1328-7 gibi bir şey
    dim_1 = mat.shape[1]
    x = np.zeros((dim_0, TIME_STEPS, dim_1))
    y = np.zeros((dim_0,))

    for i in tqdm(range(dim_0)):
        x[i] = mat[i:TIME_STEPS + i]
        y[i] = mat[TIME_STEPS + i, y_col_index]
    print("length of time-series i/o", x.shape, y.shape)
    return x, y


def trim_dataset(mat, batch_size):
    """
    trims dataset to a size that's divisible by BATCH_SIZE
    """
    no_of_rows_drop = mat.shape[0]%batch_size
    if(no_of_rows_drop > 0):
        return mat[:-no_of_rows_drop]
    else:
        return mat

x_t, y_t = build_timeseries(x_train, 0)
#x_t =3 boyutlu besleme verileri
#y_t =de sonuç satırının timestepsten sonraki kısmı(1. değişkeni aldık)
x_t = trim_dataset(x_t, BATCH_SIZE)#xtrain
y_t = trim_dataset(y_t, BATCH_SIZE)#ytrain(sonuc)
x_temp, y_temp = build_timeseries(x_test, 0)
x_val, x_test_t = np.split(trim_dataset(x_temp, BATCH_SIZE),2)
y_val, y_test_t = np.split(trim_dataset(y_temp, BATCH_SIZE),2)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, batch_input_shape=(BATCH_SIZE, TIME_STEPS, x_t.shape[2]), dropout=0.0, recurrent_dropout=0.0, stateful=True, kernel_initializer='random_uniform'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=kr.optimizers.rmsprop(0.01))

csv_logger = kr.callbacks.CSVLogger('sonuclar.log')

history = model.fit(x_t, #train girdiler
                    y_t, #train çıktılar
                    epochs=200,
                    verbose=2,
                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                    shuffle=False,
                    validation_data=((trim_dataset(x_val, BATCH_SIZE)),
                                     (trim_dataset(y_val, BATCH_SIZE))),
                    callbacks=[csv_logger])

grafik1=model.predict(x_test_t)
```

and thats my results like:

```
.
.
.
.
Epoch 192/200
 - 0s - loss: 3.8528e-04 - val_loss: 1.0298e-04
Epoch 193/200
 - 0s - loss: 3.1330e-04 - val_loss: 3.7064e-04
Epoch 194/200
 - 0s - loss: 9.6561e-04 - val_loss: 1.4455e-04
Epoch 195/200
 - 0s - loss: 2.7916e-04 - val_loss: 3.4224e-04
Epoch 196/200
 - 0s - loss: 8.4071e-04 - val_loss: 4.0075e-04
Epoch 197/200
 - 0s - loss: 4.9036e-04 - val_loss: 1.1518e-04
Epoch 198/200
 - 0s - loss: 3.2914e-04 - val_loss: 1.2514e-04
Epoch 199/200
 - 0s - loss: 0.0010 - val_loss: 3.6713e-04
Epoch 200/200
 - 0s - loss: 4.0553e-04 - val_loss: 1.7644e-04
2020-04-08 14:23:10.216020: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:217] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Invalid argument: Specified a list with shape [128,4] from a tensor with shape [32,4]
     [[{{node lstm_1/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorListFromTensor}}]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/phylo/PycharmProjects/Keras1/kerassecond.py", line 80, in <module>
    grafik1=model.predict(x_test_t)
  File "/home/phylo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1462, in predict
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "/home/phylo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 324, in predict_loop
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py", line 3727, in __call__
    outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1551, in __call__
    return self._call_impl(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1591, in _call_impl
    return self._call_flat(args, self.captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1692, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 545, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Specified a list with shape [128,4] from a tensor with shape [32,4]
     [[node lstm_1/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorListFromTensor (defined at home/phylo/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3009) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_10579]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph


Process finished with exit code 1
```

When i change my Batch size is 128 and my predict code (grafik1=model.predict(x_test_t)), i am getting this error but if i try to change my BATC_SIZE to 32, This code dont giving any error. why? I tested different values and i see, 128 Batchsize is the best of me. How can i solve this problem?

[image: DATA SET]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Keras documentation pages, for the predict function (https://keras.io/models/sequential/):

> **batch_size**: Integer or `None`. Number of samples per gradient update. If unspecified, `batch_size` will default to 32. Do not specify the `batch_size` is your data is in the form of symbolic tensors, generators, or `keras.utils.Sequence` instances (since they generate batches).

Specifying `batch_size` will therefore likely fix the issue:

```
grafik1=model.predict(x_test_t, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```